# Website content

Tags: html, css

I've tried many ways to code but none of them works. The 3 products are listed vertically in one column. But I have no idea on how to separate the the following `<div>` containing 6 others product into different columns beside it. Can you help me to solve this?

Or, in other ways, can the `<div>` is actually aligned into 3 products per row, not in column?

```
<div class="products-right-grids-position1">
<h4>BUN BOY Bakery</h4>
<p>Best Bakery in Town </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="products-right-grids-bottom">
<div class="col-md-4 products-right-grids-bottom-grid">

<?php 
echo getPros();
?>

<?php 
echo getBreadPros();
?>

</div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Why are you including PHP code in your sample? How are we supposed to know what HTML will be created from that PHP?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on here

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```